# Same PropertyChanged for all Linq-to-SQL classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Every Linq-to-SQL class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Thus every Linq-to-SQL class has its own `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` event, which is raised when properties of generated class are changed.

My application has the same logging logic repeated in all PropertyChanged handlers. I tried somehow to transparently reuse that code. I created base `public class XDbObject : INotifyPropertyChanged` and inherited everything from it. But children classes still use their PropertyChanged events.

Is there any way to setup same PropertyChanged handler for all Linq-to-SQL generated classes?

Comment: `But children classes still use their PropertyChanged events` What do you mean?

Comment: No chance. Contrary to Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL doesn't have any hooks to change the generated code. But suppose you could, what kind of object would be the event consumer?